# Typecasting and assigning a void pointer variable to an Integer variable in VC++.

Tags: c++, visual-c++, type-conversion, void-pointers

I have a C++ function:

```
void Func(void* param)
{
   int a;
   a= (int*)param;
}
```

I think what I have done **a= (int*)param;**  is correct. But don't know why I am getting compilation error as "Cannot convert from int* to int.

Can anyone kindly help me in thi regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `std::intptr_t` from header `<cstdint>` instead of `int` if you really intend to do this (which you shouldn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `a` is an `int` and not an `int*`.  Did you mean:

```
int a;
a = *((int*)param);
```

instead?

Answer (score 1):

After casting `param` to `(int*)`, you need to **dereference** it to use it as a variable:

```
int a;
int* intParamPtr = (int*)param;
a = *intParamPtr; // * is dereference operator
```